# multiple for return in xpath expression

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

(I'm quite fuzzy on what is XQuery and what is XPath)

I have a scenario where I want to go (in a 'select' attribute in an XSLT 3.0 statement)

```
for $x in $xs
for $y in $ys
return kooks:foo($x,$y)
```

I get (from saxon he)

```
XPST0003  expected "return", found "for"
```

So, I can sidestep this by going (and using sequence flattening)...

```
for $x in $xs
return 
   (for $y in $ys
   return kooks:foo($x,$y))
```

Is this sensible? is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I think `for $x in $xs, $y in $ys return ..` might work.

Comment: achcchchc...let me try

Comment: expected "$", found "for"

Comment: its not the end of the world, but if i came across my expression I'd scratch my head

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-for-expressions has the details about the syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problems evaluating e.g.

```
let 
  $xs := (1 to 5), 
  $ys := reverse(1 to 5)
return
  for $x in $xs, $y in $ys
  return sum(($x, $y))
```

with Saxon HE 12 as XPath 3.1.

Comment: achchhc...I've done 
for $x in $xs, for $y in $ys
my mistake